# App crashes after upgrading to unity 2019.3.7f when using lower android version

Tags: unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I've created my app in unity 2019.2.5f and my .aab build works at my samsung SM-J710GN and lower android versions. The only problem in 2019.2.5f is it has a bug that S-pen does not work. So I upgraded to 2019.3.7f. The problem now is when I test my app to samsung SM-J710GN, it crashes. I check logcat and found a line with `il2cpp/patch.config' is missing`. I don't know if this is the error but the same line appears in my samsung_SM-A530F and it runs perfectly.

Here are the logcat logs.

```
D/Unity(31130): CommandLine:  
I/Unity(31130): onResume
D/Unity(31130): SetWindow 0 0xeb4cf008
D/Unity(31130): SetWindow 0 0xeb4cf008
I/Unity(31130): windowFocusChanged: true
D/Unity(31130): Enabling Unity systrace
D/Unity(31130): [VFS] Mount /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/base.apk
D/Unity(31130): [VFS] Mount /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk
I/Unity(31130): SystemInfo CPU = ARM64 FP ASIMD AES, Cores = 8, Memory = 1821mb
I/Unity(31130): SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 8 big (mask: 0xff), 0 little (mask: 0x0)
I/Unity(31130): ApplicationInfo com.MyCompany.MyApp version 0.1 build 9f7d5438-69ea-4de7-84be-c1bccddd034d
I/Unity(31130): Built from '2019.3/staging' branch, Version '2019.3.7f1 (6437fd74d35d)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Enabled'
D/Unity(31130): Script Patching: Patch files are not available, '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.MyCompany.MyApp/cache/ScriptOnly/2019.3.7f1/il2cpp/patch.config' is missing.
D/Unity(31130): PlayerConnection initialized from /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data (debug = 0)
D/Unity(31130): PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55482
D/Unity(31130): PlayerConnection initialized unix socket : Unity-com.MyCompany.MyApp
D/Unity(31130): Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.254.102 [Port] 55482 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 3076295348 [EditorId] 3179775812 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(samsung_SM-J710GN@192.168.254.102) [Debug] 1 [PackageName] AndroidPlayer [ProjectName] MyApp" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
D/Unity(31130): Waiting for connection from host on [0.0.0.0:55482]...
D/Unity(31130): Remaining time:8s
D/Unity(32306): Timed out. Continuing without host connection.
D/Unity(32306): Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55438]
D/Unity(32306): Starting managed debugger on port 56471
E/CRASH(32306): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
E/CRASH(32306): Version '2019.3.7f1 (6437fd74d35d)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
E/CRASH(32306): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j7xeltedx/j7xelte:6.0.1/MMB29K/J710GNDXU1API5:user/release-keys'
E/CRASH(32306): Revision: '6'
E/CRASH(32306): ABI: 'arm'
E/CRASH(32306): Timestamp: 2020-04-07 22:37:49+0800
E/CRASH(32306): pid: 32306, tid: 32319, name: UnityMain  >>> com.MyCompany.MyApp <<<
E/CRASH(32306): uid: 10491
E/CRASH(32306): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xfb59e0cc
E/CRASH(32306):     r0  01ffffff  r1  0000000e  r2  701c4000  r3  00000001
E/CRASH(32306):     r4  daea3dc0  r5  00000000  r6  f359e0d0  r7  d7d3c040
E/CRASH(32306):     r8  fffffff8  r9  00000000  r10 00000000  r11 f359e098
E/CRASH(32306):     ip  00000000  sp  f359e070  lr  d88f6f28  pc  d88f6f54
E/CRASH(32306): backtrace:
E/CRASH(32306):       #00 pc 002dbf54  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #01 pc 002dbf00  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #02 pc 002f484c  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #03 pc 002da2f0  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #04 pc 002d659c  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #05 pc 002dc504  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #06 pc 002e4f58  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #07 pc 002e5bd8  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #08 pc 002e5ce4  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #09 pc 0032d050  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #10 pc 002ed38c  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #11 pc 002a5a14  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp_init+40) (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/CRASH(32306):       #12 pc 004863fd  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (InitializeIl2CppFromMain(core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&, int, char const**, bool)+188) (BuildId: fa4efc9bdc22d7868eb4de9f0e6e2b8fb81c9505)
E/CRASH(32306):       #13 pc 004e2597  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityInitApplication()+2526) (BuildId: fa4efc9bdc22d7868eb4de9f0e6e2b8fb81c9505)
E/CRASH(32306):       #14 pc 004e3051  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+100) (BuildId: fa4efc9bdc22d7868eb4de9f0e6e2b8fb81c9505)
E/CRASH(32306):       #15 pc 00505ac1  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+40) (BuildId: fa4efc9bdc22d7868eb4de9f0e6e2b8fb81c9505)
E/CRASH(32306):       #16 pc 0083c0f9  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/oat/arm/base.odex (boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender()+76)
E/CRASH(32306): Tombstone written to: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.MyCompany.MyApp/files/tombstone_02
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): Process: com.MyCompany.MyApp, PID: 32306
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain]
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): Unity version     : 2019.3.7f1
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): Device model      : samsung SM-J710GN
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): Device fingerprint: samsung/j7xeltedx/j7xelte:6.0.1/MMB29K/J710GNDXU1API5:user/release-keys
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): Caused by: java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): Version '2019.3.7f1 (6437fd74d35d)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j7xeltedx/j7xelte:6.0.1/MMB29K/J710GNDXU1API5:user/release-keys'
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): Revision: '6'
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): ABI: 'arm'
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): Timestamp: 2020-04-07 22:37:49+0800
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): pid: 32306, tid: 32319, name: UnityMain  >>> com.MyCompany.MyApp <<<
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): uid: 10491
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xfb59e0cc
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):     r0  01ffffff  r1  0000000e  r2  701c4000  r3  00000001
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):     r4  daea3dc0  r5  00000000  r6  f359e0d0  r7  d7d3c040
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):     r8  fffffff8  r9  00000000  r10 00000000  r11 f359e098
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):     ip  00000000  sp  f359e070  lr  d88f6f28  pc  d88f6f54
E/AndroidRuntime(32306): backtrace:
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #00 pc 002dbf54  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #01 pc 002dbf00  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #02 pc 002f484c  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #03 pc 002da2f0  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #04 pc 002d659c  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #05 pc 002dc504  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #06 pc 002e4f58  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #07 pc 002e5bd8  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #08 pc 002e5ce4  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #09 pc 0032d050  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #10 pc 002ed38c  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #11 pc 002a5a14  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp_init+40) (BuildId: dd1e65ba48cc1f28d47b6b27d8bab2a508249c3d)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #12 pc 004863fd  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (InitializeIl2CppFromMain(core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&, int, char const**, bool)+188) (BuildId: fa4efc9bdc22d7868eb4de9f0e6e2b8fb81c9505)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #13 pc 004e2597  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityInitApplication()+2526) (BuildId: fa4efc9bdc22d7868eb4de9f0e6e2b8fb81c9505)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #14 pc 004e3051  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+100) (BuildId: fa4efc9bdc22d7868eb4de9f0e6e2b8fb81c9505)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #15 pc 00505ac1  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+40) (BuildId: fa4efc9bdc22d7868eb4de9f0e6e2b8fb81c9505)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):       #16 pc 0083c0f9  /data/app/com.MyCompany.MyApp-1/oat/arm/base.odex (boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender()+76)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):    at libil2cpp.0x2dbf54(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):    at libil2cpp.0x2dbf00(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):    at libil2cpp.0x2f484c(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):    at libil2cpp.0x2da2f0(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):    at libil2cpp.0x2d659c(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):    at libil2cpp.0x2dc504(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):    at libil2cpp.0x2e4f58(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):    at libil2cpp.0x2e5bd8(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32306):    at libil2cpp.0x2e5ce4(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(2590):   Force finishing activity com.MyCompany.MyApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
```

Comment: Looking at you seg fault, try disabling LI2CPP.  Just for grins, see what happens.

Comment: @jiveturkey Disabling iI2CPP means I'll switch it to mono?

Comment: I no it's not ultimately what you want to do but it will start eliminating variables for you.